# Disambiguation of method signatures for PHP "overloading"

Tags: php, overloading

I have a method that supports complex "overloading" by utilizing func_get_args to determine the method signature. In some situations however, the argument types are too ambiguous to make a distinction.

```
designGarment('my shirt', SIZES::XXL, FABRICS::COTTON);
designGarment('my dress', FABRICS::SILK, ATTIRES::PARTY);
```

In the example above, both method signatures resolve to STRING, INT, INT because SIZES, FABRICS and ATTIRES are classes with integer constants defined for their respective properties. I want to be able to distinguish a (STRING, SIZES, FABRICS) signature from a (STRING, FABRICS, ATTIRES) signature. Is this possible in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside @Brad Christie answer there are few others:

1. Recomended: use arguments in constant order and null as default values for missing ones

   ```
   function designGarment($name, $size = null, $fabric = null, $attire = null){
       if(!is_null($size)){ }
       //etc
   }

   designGarment('my dress', NULL, FABRICS::SILK, ATTIRES::PARTY);
   ```
2. Use Object to store optional arguments

   ```
   $options = new stdClass;
   $options->size = SIZES::XXL; 
   function designGarment($name, $options = null){

   }
   ```
3. Make separeate object for every type of property

   ```
   function designGarment(){
       foreach(func_get_args() as $arg){
           if($arg instanceof Size){ }
       }
   }
   designGarment($name, new Size('XXL'), new Fabric('WOOL'));
   ```
4. Similar to above, but to have separate object for every type and value of property (not recommended, but I've seen some cases using this)

   ```
   class Size{ public $size; }
   class SizeXXL extends Size{
       public function __construct(){ $this->size = SIZES::XXL; } 
   }
   designGarment($name, new SizeXXL);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Use objects instead of guessing arguments:

```
class Garment
{
  var $name;
  var $size;
  var $fabric;
  var $attires;
}

$Garment = new Garment(...);
function designGarment($Garment);
```

Or use an array of key/value pairs to explicitly specify arguments and their values:

```
designGarment(array(
  'name' => 'my dress',
  'fabric' => FABRICS::SILK,
  'attires' => ATTIRES::PARTY
));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should clarify, I am building a framework and the method in question does allow a single array parameter to supply key/value pairs, but I'd like to give the option not to use an array. Your first example defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to acheive, I might as well just pass the constructor arguments directly into designGarment or expose a "design" method for your Garment object.

Comment: @leo: Well, php doesn't support named parameters so I'm not sure how else you'd like to tackle this other than setting (very separated) integer values to the different constants and checking if they're within that property's range. e.g. "If it's between 1-100, it must be a FABRICS:: value, 250-500 is ATTIRES, etc.

Comment: Yes, I was considering something to that effect, perhaps delimited strings ala FAB_1, FAB_2 etc..